# What is the operator for "Less than or Equal to" in Java?

Tags: java, equals

I am familiar with Actionscript programming, and I often used the "<=" (less than or equal to) or ">=" (greater than or equal to) operators.

However in Eclipse, I have been unable to use such operators.
Here's my situation.
Defined variable:

```
final EditText UserNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

And here's the use:

```
if (UserNumber <= 10){ }
```

I'm sure this is a very easy/quick fix but I have been unable to locate what should be used in this situation.

And this is the error I'm getting:

> The operator <= is undefined for the argument type(s) EditText, int

Comment: That's _Java_.  Eclipse is just an IDE.

Comment: Can we assume you are using java?

Comment: Please learn to actually **read** error messages. This one very clearly says you're trying to compare types that are incompatible (`EditText` and `int`).

Comment: please, brush up your java before starting android.

Comment: Dang Ken. Don't take your anger out on the guy. Be nice.

Comment: @NixitPatel - please don't discourage people from developing software. Don't hate. Elevate

Answer (score 10):

As the error clearly states, you can't compare an `EditText` instance to a number.

You probably want to get the `EditText`'s value.

Comment: Thanks everyone! And ya, oops I meant JAVA! :) Also, so I take it the operator is still the same, it's just I was using it to compare two irrelevant things?

Comment: Exactly.  Java is not an acronym.

Comment: lol sheesh so literal! Also, I forgot to mention that the "UserNumber" IS in fact a number, but it's in a "edit text" box in the GUI.

Comment: It's not a number.  It's a text box that contains a string that represents a number.  You'll need to use `Integer.parseInt(String)` to turn the `String` into an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

As a solution, use this instead

```
Integer.parseInt(UserNumber.getText().toString());
```

In your case, this works fine,

```
 if((Integer.parseInt(UserNumber.getText().toString()) )<=10)
            {
               //Do what you want 
            }
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! But for some reason it's still giving me the same error. Theoretically, it should be converting the number entered by the user (read as a string of text by the computer), into a useable/comparable integer, right?

Comment: @Inferno parseInt parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. See the edit if you used it like that, this worked for me, and if you still get the error, the error is something else. pls check your code once again. cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to get the text from the edit text view, then if it is a Integer get the value from the string.

```
        Integer.parseInt(UserNumber.getText().toString());
```

As mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer.valueOf(UserNumber.getText().toString())<=10
```

Comment: Oh thanks lol! Wow I think I need to go to bed if I didn't even realize to include the operator! Thanks everyone for your help! I swear I spend the most amount of time on the simplest things!

Answer (score 0):

Dangerous bend!  You cannot use <= etc to compare Java objects. You need to use a compareTo method if it is implemented. This goes especially for strings.